# Store View Custom price attribute shows $0.00 in Magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

This is for Magento 1.9
I created a new Price attribute say 'custom_price'.
In price.phtml, it's called via

```
<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->currency($_product->getCustomPrice(), true, false); ?>
```

When the custom price is entered under Default Values, the price shows. When set only in store view, price just says $0.00

Attribute is set to be viewable in Product Listing page.

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: What is the result of just `$_product->getCustomPrice()`?

Comment: What is the attribute set up in terms of visibility is it global, website or store? Is the attribute set on the correct store?

Comment: Attribute scope is website, attribute set in correct store. Results of $_product->getCustomPrice() is $0.00

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

```
   $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
         ->setStoreId($storeId)
         ->load($_product->getId());
    echo $product->getCustomPrice(); die();
```

Please let me know what is your result?